# GROQ query to find all posts with a specific location

Tags: reactjs, database, fetch, sanity, groq

I have set a sanity schema that present a restaurant and the restaurant has an array of locations that accept multiple string(cities) as shown in the picture.

I am asking if there is a way to fetch data from sanity using the location array. so for example I want to return all the restaurants that has "Casablanca" in the  location array. just like we use the slug in this example :
*[slug.current == "${slug}"] {
...,
sections[]{
...,
dishes[]->{
...,
}
}
}

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I managed to came up with :

```js
 *[_type == "restaurant"] {
   ...,
}[location[] match 'dakhla']
```